# How can I fix my Latex Chart code to delete the error

Tags: charts, latex

My chart is not working as I had hoped. Instead of a legend below the chart, I only see an S in a box. Does anyone know why? Specifically: Instead of a box with the legend being displayed, I only get a box with an "S".

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
width=16cm,
height=8cm,
xlabel={Year},
ylabel={Stock of Operational Robots in Major Countries 1994-2014},
xmin=1994, xmax=2014,
ymin=0, ymax=450,
xtick={1994,1996,1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2010,2012,2014,2015},
ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400},
xtick style={draw=none},
ytick style={draw=none},
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
color=blue,
mark=square,
]
table [col sep=comma,x=Year,y=China] {data.csv};

\addplot[
color=red,
mark=triangle,
]
table [col sep=comma,x=Year,y=Japan] {data.csv};

\addplot[
color=green,
mark=diamond,
]
table [col sep=comma,x=Year,y=US] {data.csv};

\addplot[
color=purple,
mark=*,
]
table [col sep=comma,x=Year,y=SouthKorea] {data.csv};

\addplot[
color=orange,
mark=star,
]
table [col sep=comma,x=Year,y=Germany] {data.csv};

% Legende
\legend{China, Japan, US, South Korea, Germany}
\legend style={
    at={(0.5,-0.15)}, % unterhalb des Diagramms zentriert
    anchor=north,
    draw=none, % keine Linie um die Legende
    font=\footnotesize, % Schriftgröße der Legende anpassen
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}, % Abstand zwischen Einträgen in der Legende anpassen
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is a picture of the outcome]

Does somebody know why it's not working?

Comment: Please edit your code to make a (theoretically) compilable [mre]. Add a class and the necessary package. Please also provide a `data.csv` file so we can test your code.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `\legend style={...}` is wrong. You can either use `\pgfplotsset{legend style={...}}` or use `legend style={...}` in the optional argument of the `axis` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
width=16cm,
height=8cm,
xlabel={Year},
ylabel={Stock of Operational Robots in Major Countries 1994-2014},
%xmin=1994, xmax=2014,
%ymin=0, ymax=450,
%xtick={1994,1996,1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2010,2012,2014,2015},
%ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400},
xtick style={draw=none},
ytick style={draw=none},
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
  legend style={
    at={(0.5,-0.15)}, % unterhalb des Diagramms zentriert
    anchor=north,
    draw=none, % keine Linie um die Legende
    font=\footnotesize, % Schriftgröße der Legende anpassen
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}, % Abstand zwischen Einträgen in der Legende anpassen
}
]

\addplot[
color=blue,
mark=square,
]
coordinates {
            (2003, 0.03)(2005, 0.14)(2007, 0.61)(2009, 2.32)(2011, 7.45)(2013, 17.24)(2015, 33.25)(2017, 49.34)
            };

\addplot[
color=red,
mark=triangle,
]
coordinates {
            (2003, 0.03)(2005, 0.14)(2007, 0.61)(2009, 2.32)(2011, 7.45)(2013, 17.24)(2015, 33.25)(2017, 49.34)
            };

\addplot[
color=green,
mark=diamond,
]
coordinates {
            (2003, 0.03)(2005, 0.14)(2007, 0.61)(2009, 2.32)(2011, 7.45)(2013, 17.24)(2015, 33.25)(2017, 49.34)
            };

\addplot[
color=purple,
mark=*,
]
coordinates {
            (2003, 0.03)(2005, 0.14)(2007, 0.61)(2009, 2.32)(2011, 7.45)(2013, 17.24)(2015, 33.25)(2017, 49.34)
            };

\addplot[
color=orange,
mark=star,
]
coordinates {
            (2003, 0.03)(2005, 0.14)(2007, 0.61)(2009, 2.32)(2011, 7.45)(2013, 17.24)(2015, 33.25)(2017, 49.34)
            };

% Legende
\legend{China, Japan, US, South Korea, Germany}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! Do you know how I place the legend horizontally at this position, i.e. each element next to each other instead of underneath each other?

Comment: @geekgeekgeek If you have a new question, please ask a new question